# How to change the color according to user input?

Tags: android, colors, textview

I want to create an app which has 2 text views and 2 edit texts. Here the logic is, when input is <=30, background color of textview turns blue. If  input is <=60, turns red. if inut is more than 60,turns green.

So according to the inputs given in the both edit texts at a time, the background color of the text view should change according to the logic.(input given in edit text and output shown as background color of text view).

Here is my code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
     TextView txblue,txred;
     EditText inp1,inp2;
     Button ok;
    int numbr = 1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.txblue = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tblue);
        this.txred = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tred);
        this.inp1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        this.inp2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        this.ok = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        inp1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Only 10 numbers",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.show();
            }
        });


    inp2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Only 10 numbers",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
    });


    this.ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
     {


         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) 
         {

             if (numbr <= 30)
            {
                txblue.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            else  if (numbr <= 60)

                {
                txblue.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }

             else
             {
                 txblue.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); 
             }
            return;

         }
     });
    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {

     if (numbr <= 30)
        {
            txblue.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        else  if (numbr <= 60)

            {
            txblue.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

     else
     {
         txblue.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); 
     }
        return;

    }
}
```

Comment: so where is your question?

Comment: ok, what is your problem...

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i=Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            if (i <= 30)
            {
                //blue color bkg
            }
            else if (i <= 60)
            {
                //red color bkg
            }
            else if (i > 60)
            {
                //green color bkg
            }
        }
    });
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Thank u for the answer.It worked a bit. But now the Problem is, when i entered  50, it turns blue. Actually according to the logic, its wrong.

Comment: your input is text or a number?

Comment: Number. I entered 50 in the edit text 1 and clicked ok button. The background color of the textview turned blue.

Comment: Thank u so much. it worked. Now i understood where i went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, I hope it will help you.

```
final EditText inputtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    inputtext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(inputtext.getText().toString()) <= 30) {
                TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                t1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                t2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(inputtext.getText().toString()) <= 60) {
                TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                t1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                t2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }else if (Integer.parseInt(inputtext.getText().toString()) > 60) {
                TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                t1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                t2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer too. It also worked. Thanks once again.